# How to correctly close OutputStream?

Tags: java, file, outputstream

Below you find the constructor of a server in order to setup it. In a few words, it restore its state from the last time that it was up reading a `List` of objects (called `log`) and two `int` (called `currentTerm` and `votedFor`). Any time that any of these "volatile" fields will be updated, the relative file will have to be updated too (and so make upadate the consistent state), so I need the two `ObjectOutPutStream` called `metadataWriter` and `logWriter`. Since the server could go down **in any moment**, I cannot write any `close()` method. Do you think that the only possible solution in order to avoid an `EOFException` the next time that I setup the server (during the reading operation) is to `flush()` the output stream everytime (like I've done on the last lines of the code)?

```
   public ServerRMI(...)
    {
        ...
        log = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //if Log file exists then should exists Metadata too
            if(Files.exists(Paths.get("Server" + id + "Log"), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS))
            {
                reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Server"+id+"Log"));
                try
                {
                    while(true)
                        log.add((LogEntry) reader.readObject());
                }
                catch (EOFException e){}
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Server"+id+"Metadata"));
                currentTerm = reader.readInt();
                votedFor = reader.readInt();
            }
            else//if it is the first time that the server is set up initialize all persistent fields
            {
                currentTerm = 1;
                votedFor = -1;
                log = new ArrayList<LogEntry>();
            }
            logWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Server"+id+"Log"));
            metadataWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Server" + id + "Metadata"));
            //since creating a new ObjectOutputStream overwrite the old file with the an empty one, as first thing we rewrite the old content
            for(LogEntry entry : log)
                logWriter.writeObject(entry);
            metadataWriter.writeInt(currentTerm);
            metadataWriter.writeInt(votedFor);
            metadataWriter.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

I don't think that the try-with-resources **in every method which use them** (and so each method that update server's state) as someone have suggested is a feasible solution, since it would be ok for the `metadata` file (the two `int` written on it are always replaced at every update/write to file) but for the `log` file it would mean to write the whole list every time that it is changed (the operation made on it are not only appen, but replacement too!), which I think that it's not so good for performance!

Comment: write `.close` in `finally` block

Comment: The server can 'go down at any moment' during its constructor how? And why do you think you need to 'avoid an `EOFException`'?

Comment: what is `while(true)`? who will break the loop?

Comment: @Braj The EOFException ;)

Comment: @EJP I never said that the server can go down during its constructor. After that the constructor has finished, the server can go down in every moment, and so the `OutpuStreamObject` (which are class field, not constructor local variable) are not correctly closed.

Comment: What you said is precisely that it 'can go down in any moment'. If that's not what you meant, you should amend your question.

Comment: @EJP well,you made surely a point :P But even if it could go down during its own constructor, what should it have to do with the original question?

Comment: The only code you've posted is the constructor. Either the server can go down during this constructor or it can't. Which is it? And if it can't, what *is* the actual question? You seem to be asking merely whether `flush()` flushes, which seems a pretty pointless thing to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use try-with-resource and write the whole collection at once and you don't have to read until you get an exception. You can write meta data at the start.

```
List<LogEntry> entries = ..
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(....)) {
    out.writeObject(currentTerm);
    out.writeObject(votedeFor);
    out.writeObject(entries);
}
```

to read you can do

```
String currentTerm = "none";
String votedFor = "no-one";
List<LogEntry> entries = Collections.emptyList();
try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(....)) {
    currentTerm = (String) in.readObject();
    votedFor = (String) in.readObject();
    entries = (List<LogEntry>) in.readObject();
}
```

Note: this needs Java 7, but given it's about to be EOL, I suggest upgrading to Java 8 if you can.

> which I think that it's not so good for performance!

This is a very different question but you would still use try-with-resource.  A solution is to only append new entries.  To do this you need,

- a protocol on top of ObjectOutputStream which supports appending to a file. ObjectOutputStream won't do this for you, instead you need to write blocks of data and you need a means to sticking these together.
- a way to determine what has changed/added since the last write to disk and only write the changes to disk.

Befor eyou assume performance is bad, you should test it as you might find it is not worth the added complexity to save a few milli-second.

BTW if you really care about performance, don't use ObjectOutputStream, it is generic and flexible, but very slow.

> so the OutpuStreamObject (which are class field, not constructor local variable) are not correctly closed.

In this case the file will be corrupted.  You need a means of validating the file and truncating invalid data.

---

Take a look at a library I wrote. [Chronicle Queue](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue) It may solve many of your problems as it supports

- continuous writing from multiple threads, processes or machines.
- if a process or thread dies while writing it, the corrupted entry is truncated or ignored.
- if a process dies between writes, there is no loss of data.
- it support more efficient means of serialization.
- it can be read by multiple threads/processes while it is being written with micro-second latency.
- it can be replicated to multiple machines for distribution.
- entries can be randomly accesses by an index or by binary search.

Comment: Added "important note" section about your answer

Comment: @justHelloWorld `for the log file it would mean to write the whole list every time that it is changed` This has nothing to do with how the file is closed, it is to do with how it is written which is an unrelated subject.  You are aware that you cannot append to an ObjectOutputStream.  Can you clarify what your real question is?

Comment: Well, I find out now that there is no way to append something with the ObjectOutpuStream O.o Thanks for the information...well, it seems that the only solution in order to update the file relative to `log` is to write everytime the whole `log` object, don't you think? Thanks anyway

Comment: @justHelloWorld The ObjectOutputStream has a header and if you try to append to it an existing file, it will write the header again in the stream which will make no sense to it.

Comment: @justHelloWorld There are alternatives, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

[The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Example

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BhargavModi given Java 7 is about to be EOL, time to move to Java 8.

Comment: Added "important note" section about your answer